# Converting MFCC to FFT

Tags: machine-learning, feature-extraction

I have 128 bin FFT data for an audio file. I want to convert these FFT into MFCC of size 14, 20, 40. Is there some library which converts directly FFT to MFCC.

P.S - I dont have the actual audio file.